# Using NSPredicate how to filter value from core data

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have one entity & three Attribute called as  name, version, Company.
i want to filter value from company attribute like as "Fast Food".

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"('company' contains[c] 'Fast Foood')"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"Pre %@",predicate);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    // Set self's events array to the mutable array, then clean up.
    [self setDataarr:mutableFetchResults];
```

but i cant do this plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not enclose the attribute name in quotation marks:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company CONTAINS[c] 'Fast Foood'"];
```

or better

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company CONTAINS[c] %@", @"Fast Foood"];
```

Btw.: Your predicate searches for "Fast Foood", not for "Fast Food".

---

*(In response to your comments)* You should define entities *Category*  and *Dishes* with a one-to-many relationship:

[image]

Now you can find all dishes for a given category with the following fetch request:

```
NSString *catName = @"Desert";
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Dish"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category.name = %@", catName];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: @AbhishekRathore: If you describe the problem I will try to help.

Comment: Actually i want to fetch the information on basis of a category, for example, lets take a Restaurant Menu, in this i want to show the values on the Menu card based on values entered by Admin preparing the List of Items.
For Example, Ice Cream is inserted in Dessert Category, Taomoato Soup is inserted in Soup Category. This items needs to be shown in Menu as per category chosen.

Comment: @AbhishekRathore: I am confused. Your question is about a *Device* entity with a *company* attribute. Now you talk about dishes with a category. Please tell me what entities and relationships you have defined.

Comment: The dishes are dependent on the category defined, so when a dish is attached to a category, it should be displayed on the menu according to the insertion.Let me know if this suffice.

Comment: @AbhishekRathore: This is completely different from your question!! - So you have an entity *Dish* and and entity *Category*? What attributes and relationships are defined? What do you mean by "display on menu"?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h39Qw0iRIU&feature=youtu.be
Please check this , the dishes are shown on the basis of Categories

Comment: @AbhishekRathore: I have updated my answer. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks Martin, i appreciate your response , but since i need some more assistance, can it be possbile for you to send me a communication id, be it Skype, Gmail. You can mail me at a_z24365@yahoo.com

Comment: @AbhishekRathore: I would prefer it if you update your question, or, if it is a different problem, post a new question.

Comment: Just a querry , can't i solve this problem with One Entity and Three attribute(Dish, Item, Rate)

Comment: @AbhishekRathore: And where is the category stored? And what exactly is "Dish" and "Item"?

Comment: Martin, i think your previous post of Two Entity will solve the problem, Thanks for your quick and continuous assistance.