# Using NSPredicate how to filter value from core data using 1 entity

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have one entity & three Attribute called as item, rate, category. i want to filter value from category attribute.

```
    if (managedObjectContext==nil) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    }

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Restaurantmenu" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"('category' contains[c] 'Fast Foood')"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Pre %@",predicate);
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    // Set self's events array to the mutable array, then clean up.
    [self setDataarr:mutableFetchResults];
```

but i cant do this plz help me.

Comment: And the problem is...? (also note that `'category'` should be `category` in your predicate (without single quotes))

Comment: This is an almost exact copy of your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041568/using-nspredicate-how-to-filter-value-from-core-data (for which you accepted an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your initialization of predicate from the code below and try

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category CONTAINS[c] %@", @"Fast Foood"];
```