# Filter CoreData (Parent entity and child entity)

Tags: ios, core-data, filter

Two days I have been trying to filter the CoreData and I'm still stuck.
This is my model:

```
Users < --- >> Sessions
```

I managed to create the relationship between a new session and a specific user. I also managed to get the list of all the users to display them in a tableview by this code :

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *usersDescription= [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:usersDescription];

NSError  *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchresults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]mutableCopy];
if(mutableFetchresults == nil) {
    //handle error
}

usernameDataMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i< [mutableFetchresults count]; i++)
{ Users* users = (Users *) [mutableFetchresults objectAtIndex:i];
    [usernameDataMutableArray insertObject: [users username] atIndex:i];
}
```

Now when I touch a cell called "Username1", I display a new tableView. I would like display in this tableView all the Username1 sessions.

So my question is: how can I filter all my sessions to retrieve these belong to Username1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109741/using-nspredicate-how-to-filter-value-from-core-data-using-1-entity

Comment: No the difference is that i have Two entities, and i want to filter the second one by the relationship with the first one

Comment: You need to use an NSPredicate to filter. That post should give you an idea how to do it. The number of entities is irrelevant.

Comment: No, a predicate is **NOT** required.  Just use the relationships (as I detailed in my answer) the way that they were intended to be used.

Comment: You are correct, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no filter required.

When you push the new view controller you hand off the instance of `Users` that was selected.  Then in the new view controller you ask the instance of `Users` for the `Sessions` instances that are associated with it.

```
NSSet *sessionsSet = [myUser valueForKey:@"sessions"];
```

You can also use a property if you have subclasses set up.

**This is the point of Core Data**.  It is an object graph and relationships are properties on the object instance.  Just call the appropriate method.

I would strongly suggest reading a book on Core Data as it will clear up a lot of the issues you are having with these fundamental concepts.

### Additional Comments

Entities should not be named in the plural.  Your entities should be called `User` and `Session` instead of their plural form.  The name of the relationship that points to a to-many should be plural and the name that points to the to-one should be singular.  This helps greatly with code clarity and maintainability.  Plural tends to indicate a collection of objects instead of a single object like you have now.

Comment: Last question sorry : how can i access the different attributes in my sessionSet?

Comment: It is a `NSSet` of `Sessions` instances.  They are objects.  `NSSet` is a collection, look at the documentation on how to work with a collection object.